# Codeigniter saber se o insert deu certo?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Usando o codeigniter como eu posso saber se o insert into funcionou realmente?

```
$novo_usuario=$this->db->query("INSERT INTO usuario (nome, email) VALUES ('pessoa','pessoa@gmail.com')");
```

Através da variável `$novo_usuario` como eu posso ter certeza que o cadastro deu certo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pode chamar o método [affected_rows()](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html) que retorna o número de linhas afetadas por um INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE ou checar o retorno de `query()` é um boolean

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuario (nome, email) VALUES ('pessoa','pessoa@gmail.com')";
if($this->db->query($sql)){
   echo 'Sucesso, linhas afetadas: '. $this->db->affected_rows();
}else{
  echo 'falha na operação';
  //rotina de log/tratamento de erro
}
```

Refêrencia

[Database Quick Start](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/examples.html)

[Queries](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html)